# MCP7940 - power loss during time set

Tags: rtc

To set time in MCP7940 I should stop oscillator. If power loss will occur in this moment, RTC will not resume. Is there any way to overcome this problem ? Continues time is critical for my project.

Comment: Won't the RTC be reset if the power lost anyway? And according to it's datasheet it is coming out of reset with the oscillator stopped. To prevent power loss it has an automatic switch to a backup power.

Comment: Just be sure you can detect the power loss and have enough energy storage of some form to re-enable the oscillator (and whatever else you have to do) prior to running out of energy.  Supercap maybe?  The RTC should then switch over to your battery backup.

Comment: Use a different chip that doesn't have that problem.   Analog Devices makes several that not only won't have that potential error, but they even have a bunch with built-in backup batteries.   https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/13064#/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear exactly where your question is coming from.

When you first power up the RTC, you need to start the oscillator by enabling the ST bit (the Power on Reset value is DISABLED). If power to the RTC fails, when it returns, you need to start the oscillator again - UNLESS you are using a backup power source, i.e., Vbat, in which case the oscillator keeps running and the time continues advancing.

You stop the oscillator when you are setting the time. This, in order to prevent rollover problems.

from the data sheet: *To avoid rollover issues when loading new time and date values, the oscillator/clock input should be disabled by clearing the ST bit for External Crystal mode and the EXTOSC bit for External Clock Input mode. After waiting for the OSCRUN bit to clear, the new values can be loaded and the ST or EXTOSC bit can then be re-enabled.*

If you disable the ST (or EXTOSC) bit, while you are setting the time, AND power fails while the oscillator has been stopped, then yes, the clock is not going to work and Vbat is not going to help you. You need to execute code that enables the ST bit. But when is this going to happen?

Seems to me that the only time this can happen is when your software communicating with the RTC over I2C stops running because of a power failure. So whatever is powering the machine running the code that disables the ST bit needs to have backup power. Of course, power to the RTC also needs backup, which is easily provided.

So, when you set the clock, and the ST bit is disabled through software, you need to make sure that execution of that software continues until the ST bit is enabled again. If an embedded controller is setting the clock, it should have a backup power supply to avoid this unlikely, but possible situation.

**Edited to ADD**:
@Jarek, something like the method that you suggest in a comment, is mentioned in an early version of the data sheet for the MCP7940M [DS22292A]...

*Incorrect data can appear in the Time and Date registers if a write is attempted during the time frame where these internal registers are being
incremented. The user can minimize the likeli-hood of data corruption by ensuring that any writes to the Time and Date registers occur before
the contents of the second register reach a value of 0x59H.*

I can't find mention of that in subsequent versions of the data sheets, e.g., [DS20002292C]

I can't say why that passage was removed and "minimize" does not mean "eliminate". It also might not be trivial to test how well the method works.

If this is a critical issue for you and you can't have back-up power for the main system when setting the time, maybe a different RTC that does not have the rollover issue is the way to go.

Comment: RTC has backup battery, but main system doesn't, so power failure during time setting, may leave RTC not running. I have idea, not to stop oscillator, but wait for seconds counter to change, and then set time. I hope this will avoid rollover issue.